# extract metadata of a pdf file (dimensions or orientation)

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup, pypdf

Given a pdf file, is there any way to find its page dimensions and orientations (horizontal or vertical) etc? The pypdf2 library gives a function to check for number of pages but how can I extract other info? Is it possible to use this link to find information about the file. Date of creation, number of pages, title etc? Or anything else that is possible.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

input1 = PdfFileReader(open("document1.pdf", "rb"))

# print how many pages input1 has:
print "document1.pdf has %d pages." % input1.getNumPages()
```

https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/Rotate` in order to get a page's rotation.

```
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('document1.pdf', 'rb'))
orientation = pdf.getPage(pagenumber).get('/Rotate')
```

It will yield a value in degrees. Though it may be useful for some documents, you should note, that **the page rotation by itself does not denote the orientation.** As was contributed by [@mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) in the comments.

As to other metadata, there are many things you can pull out. You can look into `PyPDF2.pdf.DocumentInformation` methods for all of them.

Comment: The page *rotation* by itself does not denote the *orientation*.

Comment: @mkl I even didn't considered it this way, thanks!